# Account Siphon on the corp with < 5 credits in the bank

Tags: android-netrunner

I use the "Account Siphon" ( https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01018 ) and the corp has only three credits. No ice is installed on HQ. How many credits will I get? 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the corp can lose up to 5 and you would gain double whatever the corp loses.

Account Siphon says:

> If successful, instead of accessing cards you may force the Corp to
>   **lose up to 5**, then **you gain 2 for each credit lost**.

So in your example, if you decide to siphon, the Corp would lose 3 and you would gain 6. Note that this is a replacement effect, and when the run is successful you can choose not to trigger it (accessing a card from HQ instead). This might be beneficial if, for example, the corp spends their remaining money on rezzing assets/ICE and there are no credits left to siphon.

Comment: Note, that IF you chose to take money, you get 2 tags disregarding of how much money you actually got.

Comment: Good point, added some additional clarification.